# How to use loop for selected dropdownlist value in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use for loop to dynamically generate dropdownlist based on value selected from dropdownlist. If selected value is 3, it has to generate 3 rows. Any one can guide me please? I used below code in view page.

```
var cntno = ViewData["cnt"] as List<demo.Models.Groupcount>;
        for (int i = 0; i < cntno.Count; i++)
        {
          <table>
             <tr>
                  <td> 
                      <div class="editor-label">
                       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fieldname)
                      </div>
                      <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.fieldname, ViewData["cnt"] as SelectList, "select count")
                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fieldname)
                     </div> 
                  </td>

            </tr>

          </table>
        }
```

Comment: You will have to use some client side code (JS or Jquery) to implement this. JQuery will be a lot easier to implement. I prefer knockout.js to implement this kind of dynamical manipulation of UI.

Comment: Use Jquery templates to render the table rows based on change event of drop down value. Refer http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates for JQuery templates

Comment: What i your issue exactly?

Comment: Hi Aravind,I guess that i need to use for loop in such way that for(int i=0;i<dropdownlistselectedvalue;i++). But the pity thing is, i don't know how to check condition in mvc4. If my dropdownlist selected value is 4, then 4 times table rows has to be created on the same page.

Comment: @Aravind : Hi Aravind,I guess that i need to use for loop in such way that for(int i=0;i<dropdownlistselectedvalue;i++). But the pity thing is, i don't know how to check condition in mvc4. If my dropdownlist selected value is 4, then 4 times table rows has to be created on the same page

Comment: Sama quick responce ponga? Just for kidding. Just wait...

Comment: That means if you select v from dropdown which have id as #ddl , then there is 3 row need to create dynamically on runtime in table have id #dynamictime. is that right ?

Comment: Yeah sure :-) And Where can i find detailed documentation for MVC4?

Comment: Then you have done it only by javascript only

Comment: @Aravind: I guessed the same. But MVC razor view does not accept document.getElementById syntax..

Comment: Just use like this $('#YOURID').val();, This will helps you in Razor view and make sure you have used the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") code in  your layout page

Comment: Ok. Let me try, and update to you.

Comment: @Aravind: I used the updated code and it is generating 5 time as the total of list count is 5. But what is the syntax for selected value of dropdownlist and how to loop it. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Just try some thing like below

```
$("#ddl").change(function () {
        var myValue = parseInt($(this).val());
        var i = 1;

        while (i <= myValue) {
            var newRow = "<td> </td>";
            $('#dynamictime td:last').after(newRow);
        }

    });
```

Comment: No effect. There is no change after selecting value from dropdownlist

Comment: $("#ddl").change(function () { var allcount = $(this).val(); $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'GroupCreation/Dynamict', data: "count=" + allcount, success: function (data) { alert('successful'); $('#dynamictimetable').html(data); } }); }); <div id="dynamictimetable"> </div>

Comment: $('#ddl').change(function () {
        var selectobject = document.getElementById("ddl")
        alert("hello" + selectobject);
        for (var i = 0; i < selectobject.length; i++) {
            alert("hi");

            location.href = '@Url.Content("~/GroupCreation/dynamict/")';
        }
    });

Comment: This code redirect to different page as i used location.href after dropdownlist value selected. But based on count it has to generate that much rows. Any help?

Comment: let me try something else.

Comment: Yep sure. I changed view as getting dropdown value from one view page and redirecting to different view page for displaying dynamic time. Now the thing is count only.